# Resource files in Angular 5 package

Tags: angular

I'm having a problem developing an Angular 5 package. My component uses some JSON files from a resources folder. But I'm only able to export my component and I need to export these files too.

**package.json**

```
{
      "name": "@package_4effect/mypackage",
      "version": "0.0.3",
      "description": "Description for mypackage",
      "private": true,
      "license": "UNLICENSED",
      "cacheDirectories": [
           "node_modules"
      ],
      "perDependencies": {
           ...
           "ng-packagr": "^2.0.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
           ...
      },
      "engines": {
           "node": ">=6.9.0"
      },
      "scripts": {
           .....
           "build": "yarn run webpack:prod",
           "build-pack": "ng-packagr -p package.json",
      }
}
```

**ng-package.json**

```
{
      "$schema": "./node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
      "lib": {
          "entryFile": "public_api.ts"
      }
}
```

**public_api.ts**

```
export * from './src/main/webapp/app/home/home.module'
export * from './src/main/webapp/app/home/home.component'
```

This code exports my Home component, however this component uses a /i18n/home.json file. I would also like to export this file.

thankful.

Comment: Is it generated from Angular Cli?

Comment: yes, but I changed the package.json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using angular cli to genarate this project, you can use assets folder to store static files.

Once you run your build, those files inside the static folder get copies to output dir (in below case wwwroot) as it is. This is how your .angular-cli.json file looks like.

[image: .angular-cli.json]